# Domain deletion error in plesk

Tags: iis, plesk

Guyzz, When I am trying to delete a domain from plesk(11.5_windows), I am getting an error. Pasting error below:

Error: DNSZone::Table::select() failed: no such row in the table

Do you ever got this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Guyzz,

Finally I got a solution. The reason for the error is that in psa.domains, the Plesk MySQL table dns_zone_id record points to a nonexistent ID record in the psa.dns_zone table for one or several domains.

Resolution is explaining below :

As a first step, delete domain which having issue from IIS then follow the steps below.

1. Access the plesk's DB (psa), for that follow the steps below : 
   --> cmd >> `cd %plesk_dir%\mysql\bin`
   --> type `mysql.exe -u admin -p -P 8306 psa` 
   --> type plesk's password
2. Find the domains that have missing IDs by running following query :

`SELECT d.name FROM domains d LEFT JOIN dns_zone z ON d.dns_zone_id=z.id WHERE z.id IS NULL;`

3. Create appropriate ID records using the following commands. Do not forget to replace <"DOMAIN-NAME"> with the real domain name and <"ADMIN-EMAIL"> with the correct email:

`INSERT INTO dns_zone (name, displayName, email) VALUES ('<DOMAIN-NAME>', '<DOMAIN-NAME>', '<ADMIN-EMAIL>');`

4. Determine the new zone ID:

`SELECT id, name FROM dns_zone where name='<DOMAIN-NAME>';`

5. Substitute the correct ID into the psa.domains table, remembering to replace <"DOMAIN-NAME"> and <"DNS-ZONE-ID"> with the correct values:

`UPDATE domains SET dns_zone_id='<DNS-ZONE-ID>' WHERE name='<DOMAIN-NAME>';`

Thats it !!! Now you should able to delete the domain from plesk !!!

Comment: As I see there is no more such error in Plesk 12 - domain can be deleted in case of some records are absent in database. In next upcoming major release there will be repair.exe tool which I believe will detect all database inconsistencies.

Comment: I could see that error in plesk 11.5 and repair.exe tools is already added on plesk 11.5 as well, but which will not help much.